# Any way to scrape a JS Rendered page without using executables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

First of all, I can't use any executables. I need to do this in pure Python but sadly requests and BS4 doesn't support JS pages and Selenium needs a webdriver which is an executable.

Does anyone knows / Is there any way to scrape a JS Rendered page using purely Python and it's modules without having to run any exe?

I'm not asking for exact solutions, only for the method and modules, if it's 
even possible.

Thank you for reading this and thank you for any constructive comments!

Have a nice day!

***For the full context***: I'm trying to run a web-scraping script on a daily basis on a cloud that doesn't allows running any exes. Tried it with Selenium and PhantomJS but got a no permission error.

Comment: What exactly is a cloud that "doesn't allow running any exes"? The Python interpreter is an executable when I last checked...

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot install 3-rd-party Python libraries or what? webdriver is executable ( `.exe`) if it's for Windows only... You can download Linux versions (e.g. [this one](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the misunderstanding, just noticed that the free version of the cloud didn't give permission for these. I got a paid one and it now works like a charm.